# Regex /gi returns different results on second call?

Tags: javascript, regex

```js
const reg = new RegExp("c6", 'gi')
console.log(reg.test("c6289"));
console.log(reg.test("c6289"));
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: it's how .test works - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Comment: This is because of the `g` flag. see specifically [this section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test#using_test_on_a_regex_with_the_global_flag)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does a RegExp with global flag give wrong results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-does-a-regexp-with-global-flag-give-wrong-results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For global flag `lastIndex` is set for each test when using test()

More details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

**Using test() on a regex with the "global" flag**

When a regex has the global flag set, test() will advance the lastIndex of the regex.

Further calls to test(str) will resume searching str starting from lastIndex. The lastIndex property will continue to increase each time test() returns true.

Note: As long as test() returns true, lastIndex will not reset—even when testing a different string!

When test() returns false, the calling regex's lastIndex property will reset to 0.